# How can I retain ASCII hex code points when writing an ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, encoding, ascii

I've loaded an xml file (Rhythmbox's database file) into Python 3 via the ElementTree parser. After modifying the tree and writing it to disk (`ElementTree.write()`) using the ascii encoding all of the ASCII hex characters that are in hex code point are converted to ASCII decimal code point. For example here is a diff containing the copyright symbol:

```
<     <copyright>&#xA9; WNYC</copyright>
---
>     <copyright>&#169; WNYC</copyright>
```

Is there any way to tell Python/ElementTree not to do this? I'd like all the hex codes to stay in hex code point.

Comment: How annoying. Sorry, I don't know ElementTree well enough to answer your question. (FWIW, my e-reader copes better with decimal than hex, so I have the opposite problem). If you don't find a way to force it to use hex, it's easy enough to convert the decimal entities to hex using regex. OTOH, in this day & age most devices have good UTF-8 support, so you could just convert those entities to Unicode and encode your output file to UTF-8.

Comment: I don't want to modify the format of the database file with a different encoding or different code point. I'd like it to stay fully compatible with Rhytmbox's format.

Comment: That makes sense. OTOH, I'd be surprised if Rhythmbox doesn't use UTF-8 for its XML files. Of course ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so it's perfectly fine to make your XML strict ASCII even if Rhythmbox does support UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. First I created a new codec error handler and then monkey patched ElementTree._get_writer() to use the new error handler. Looks like:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import io
import contextlib
import codecs


def lower_first(s):
    return s[:1].lower() + s[1:] if s else ''


def html_replace(exc):
    if isinstance(exc, (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeTranslateError)):
        s = []
        for c in exc.object[exc.start:exc.end]:
            s.append('&#%s;' % lower_first(hex(ord(c))[1:].upper()))
        return ''.join(s), exc.end
    else:
        raise TypeError("can't handle %s" % exc.__name__)

codecs.register_error('html_replace', html_replace)


# monkey patch this python function to prevent it from using xmlcharrefreplace
@contextlib.contextmanager
def _get_writer(file_or_filename, encoding):
    # returns text write method and release all resources after using
    try:
        write = file_or_filename.write
    except AttributeError:
        # file_or_filename is a file name
        if encoding == "unicode":
            file = open(file_or_filename, "w")
        else:
            file = open(file_or_filename, "w", encoding=encoding,
                        errors="html_replace")
        with file:
            yield file.write
    else:
        # file_or_filename is a file-like object
        # encoding determines if it is a text or binary writer
        if encoding == "unicode":
            # use a text writer as is
            yield write
        else:
            # wrap a binary writer with TextIOWrapper
            with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
                if isinstance(file_or_filename, io.BufferedIOBase):
                    file = file_or_filename
                elif isinstance(file_or_filename, io.RawIOBase):
                    file = io.BufferedWriter(file_or_filename)
                    # Keep the original file open when the BufferedWriter is
                    # destroyed
                    stack.callback(file.detach)
                else:
                    # This is to handle passed objects that aren't in the
                    # IOBase hierarchy, but just have a write method
                    file = io.BufferedIOBase()
                    file.writable = lambda: True
                    file.write = write
                    try:
                        # TextIOWrapper uses this methods to determine
                        # if BOM (for UTF-16, etc) should be added
                        file.seekable = file_or_filename.seekable
                        file.tell = file_or_filename.tell
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
                file = io.TextIOWrapper(file,
                                        encoding=encoding,
                                        errors='html_replace',
                                        newline="\n")
                # Keep the original file open when the TextIOWrapper is
                # destroyed
                stack.callback(file.detach)
                yield file.write

ElementTree._get_writer = _get_writer
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code (and I'd need to know more about ElementTree to fully understand it), but you can simplify the core code of `html_replace` to this: `s.append('&#x%X;' % ord(c))`, which is both more compact and faster.